# Laravel связь между таблицами

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

изучаю laravel.
Вопрос такой
Есть две таблице

[image: Таблица 2]
[image: Таблица 1]
Во второй таблице есть goods_id где хранит id из первой таблице, мне вытащить данные из второй таблице, на данный момент я хочу взять кол-во записей, на главной странице выводить всю информацию
P.s Во второй таблице нету модели

Answer (score 0):

В миграции при создании второй таблицы нужно добавить внешнюю связь:

```php
$table->foreign('goods_id')->references('id')->on('goods')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Кроме этого нужно создать модель для второй таблицы (назовем ее, условно, `GoodsInfo`. Первая модель - `Goods`) и в объекте Goods указать отношение:

```php
public function goodsInfo() {
  return $this->hasMany(GoodsInfo::class);
}
```

Далее после получения записи `Goods` обращаемся к свойству `goodsInfo`:

```php
$goods->goodsInfo
```

В этом свойстве находится коллекция со всеми записями из второй таблицы (только те, которые относятся к текущему товару). Возможно будет иметь смысл воспользоваться нетерпеливой загрузкой при получении записей

Подробнее можно почитать в документации [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) и [тут](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints)